# Software for Combinatorial Algebra sought

Tags: mathematical-software, noncommutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, combinatorics-on-words, algebraic-combinatorics

I am looking for software which helps me do *straightforward* tasks in combinatorial  algebra. Let me give an example of what I mean by a straightforward task:

I have two graded (generally noncommutative!) algebras $A$ and $B$ given by generators and homogeneous relations. Given two graded algebra homomorphisms $f,g:A\to B$ which are given by their values on the generators. I want to be able, for every fixed $n\in\mathbb N$, to know whether the kernel of $A$ in degree $n$ is contained in the kernel of $B$ in degree $n$.

This is a completely elementary linear-algebraic problem, in the sense that no Gröbner bases are required (because everything is graded), so it shouldn't be hard to do for a computer. I would like to be able to do this and many similar tasks with the least possible amount of work. In particular, I don't want to have to write scripts that translate my problem into linear algebra in order to feed them to the software (that should be done by the software), and I don't want to have to install experimental and undocumented extensions/libraries. I am not sure whether Singular does all I want in the commutative case, but it's certainly the right direction. Plural (the noncommutative algebra module of Singular) is **not** the right direction.

Comment: Have you looked into Sage?

Comment: I think GAP can be useful here. http://www.gap-system.org/

Comment: Let me mention: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85400/symbolic-computations-with-differential-operators-universal-envelopings-i-e-non

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into both (but I can't say I want to have to do anything with GAP again...) - which libraries are closest to what I want?

Comment: I think Magma algebra system is useful for your question. Also it has 
a combinatorics and linear algebra packages. 

Comment: You can try sage without installing it via their online notebook site at www.sagenb.org

Comment: Thanks, James, but installing is not my problem with Sage... it's that I have no Python experience at all. 

Comment: (To everybody else: I am currently trying to get along with Sage. I don't think GAP is reasonable for me, but I'll look into that if I fail at Sage. As for Magma, I'll talk to some users at MIT when spring term has started.)

Comment: A side remark: strictly speaking, the way you formulate your model problem (toy problem?) seems like a reduction to linear algebra would require Gr\"obner bases (or will be quite inefficient)...